# How to create folder within default images path in internal memory in android?

Tags: android

In our application we are storing images into internal memory. While fetching the data , we are fetching images by images path of internal memory.With the help of absolute path i am able to fetch path such as"../image/file.png".But i want path of folder such as "../images/filefolder/file.png". My requirement is to delete all images if i try to open another image. So i was trying to store images into one folder.By its reference i can remove the content of folder.
Please need help.

Thanks in advanced,
AA.

Comment: are you adding images in internal storage (inside data folder ) or inside the sd card ?

Comment: i am trying to store images into internal memory not in sd card.

Comment: try this to get folder path `String path=YOUR_FILE.getAbsolutePath();
  String folderpath=path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('/')-1);`

Comment: so what's the problem, just delete the directory?

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = null;
file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath()
                + CommonVariable.YOUR_FOLDER_PATH);
        // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
```

this above code is to create folder in your sdcard.

Comment: you can also delete folder programatically.
file.delete();i hope its useful to you.

Comment: i am trying to store images into internal memory not in sd card.

Comment: if in your device,sdcard not available then above code is create folder in your internal memory

Comment: @dipali `getExternalStorageDirectory()` this line creates file on external storage.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to save the image to internal directory.

```
private String saveToInternalSorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
     // path to /data/data/yourapp/app_data/imageDir
    File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Create imageDir
    File mypath=new File(directory,"profile.jpg");

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {           

        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

   // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return directory.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Explanation :

1.The Directory will be created with the given name. Javadocs is for to tell where exactly it will create the directory.

2.You will have to give the image name by which you want to save it.

To Read the file from internal memory. Use below code

```
private void loadImageFromStorage(String path)
{

try {
    File f=new File(path, "profile.jpg");
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgPicker);
    img.setImageBitmap(b);
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static long getSdCardFreeBlockSize() {
    StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath());

    long blockSize = statFs.getBlockSize();
    // long totalSize = statFs.getBlockCount() * blockSize;
    // long availableSize = statFs.getAvailableBlocks() * blockSize;
    long freeSize = statFs.getFreeBlocks() * blockSize;
    return freeSize;
}

public static long getInternalFreeBlockSize() {
    StatFs statFs = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath());
    long blockSize = statFs.getBlockSize();
    long totalSize = statFs.getBlockCount() * blockSize;
    long availableSize = statFs.getAvailableBlocks() * blockSize;
    long freeSize = statFs.getFreeBlocks() * blockSize;
    return freeSize;
}

public static int checkLargeFreeBlock() {
    long internal = getInternalFreeBlockSize();
    long sdcard = getSdCardFreeBlockSize();
    if (internal == 0 && sdcard == 0) {
        return 2;
    }
    if (internal > sdcard) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

this above code check that if your internal memory space is more then you can create your folder in internal memory.otherwise create folder in sdcard automatically..
this above function call :

```
File file = null;
        long freeblock = getSdCardFreeBlockSize();
        // 0> internal memeory
        // 0=no memory
```